# How to programmatically recycle a dllhost.exe process in COM+?

Tags: com+

How to programmatically recycle a dllhost.exe process in COM+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this. This is a com library that allows you to manage com+ application.
[Com+ Administrator Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681189(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: So, it is really possible to reuse a dllhost.exe process?

Comment: Which method needs to be callied? Is ShutdownApplication equivalent to a recycle?